# ConTeXt: How to maximize width of column depending on fixed sizes of other columns?

Tags: tables, tex-core, context, columns, width

In LaTex, I could do something like:

```
\newcolumntype{C}[1]
{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]
{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]
{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\begin{longtabu} to \linewidth
  {R{3cm} | X[l] | L{2cm}}
  ...
\end{longtabu}
```

and, as a result, the central column would take what's left of the page after right and left columns are forced to occupy fixed width. How to do the same in ConTeXt?

Comment: propably off topic but isn't there a way to set the middle column width to something like `\dimexpr\linewidth-3cm-2cm\relax`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't exactly know what the longtable macros do. I am guessing what you want, and here is one alternative.

```
\startsetups table:align
  \setupTABLE[column][1][width=3cm, align=flushright]
  \setupTABLE[column][2][width=broad, align=middle]
  \setupTABLE[column][3][width=2cm, align=flushleft]
\stopsetups

\starttext

\startTABLE[setups={table:align}]
  \NC One \NC \input ward \NC Two \NC \NR
\stopTABLE

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Can this be used with `tables`, a multi-page `table`?

Comment: Oh, I've just noticed that `tables` are deprecated, and that `TABLE` is recommended. Can you confirm that? Do you recommend me to go with `TABLE` for a multi-page table?

Comment: Yes. You need to add `\startTABLE[split=yes]` for multipage tables. The only drawback of using `TABLE` for multi-page tables is that the table only splits at the end of a row; it is not possible to split a table inside a row.